# How to dismiss all popup windows in an Activity Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-windowmanager, android-popupwindow

I am trying to dismiss a popup window which was created in `TextView` class. 
The popup window is created as:

```
    PopupWindow mPopupWindow;
    mPopupWindow =new PopupWindow(mTextView.getContext(), null,
                          com.android.internal.R.attr.textSelectHandleWindowStyle);   
    mPopupWindow.setClippingEnabled(true);
    mPopupWindow.setWindowLayoutType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL);
    mPopupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED);
```

I don't have any reference to that popup window. But I need to dismiss it.
So, Is there any way to dismiss all the popup windows in Window Manager?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your full code here?

Comment: please add full code related to popupWindow

Comment: Hi @ForamShah, I added full code. Please check and let me know if you can help me.

Comment: @W4R10CK, I added full code here. Please have a look at it and let me know if you found the answer.

Comment: do u want to cancel the window on outside touch?

Comment: @W4R10CK No. I don't have the reference object of PopupWindow. If I had I would have cancelled by `mPopupWindow.dismiss();` The PopupWindow reference is private in EasyEditPopupWindow.java class. Without reference object I can't dismiss that window. So what I am looking is dismissing a PopWindow using WindowManager or something.

Comment: you can make getter method in EasyEditPopupWindow.java to access private PopupWindow reference  and dismiss  it from outside the class.